# how can I Illustrate Graph my microbiology results ( Growth curve)?

Tags: r, excel, plot, graph, graphics

please, How to plot a curve like this for biology?  - studying the growth of a species with three replicates (three counting numbers for each date) ?
[image]

I want to plot a graph of this kind for my experiment, with dates on the x-axis and the results of my bacteria counting in 3 replicates on the y-axis, how can I do it please?

exemple of my data:

[image]

Comment: It depends on what format your data is in, which is why we recommend a _reproducible example_. Can you please include the output from `dput(mydata)` (where `mydata` is your data frame name). Please [edit] your question and copy/paste the output as text into your question.

Comment: Technically, that should not be much of a problem. Nonetheless: it seems like you're about to squeeze one boxplot plus an assumedly normal distribution out of altogether *three observations* per date. In that case the plot would suggest certainty of evidence quite beyond what's in the data. What's wrong with a plain old scatterplot?